# Can I name a temp-table field from the value of a variable?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

Hello Progress4GL Developers,

Is it possible to name a field in a temp-table from the value of a parameter.

For example let's assume I have a variable set with value "fieldname":

```
define variable randomvariable as character initial "fieldname" NO-UNDO.
```

Now, I would like to do something like this (the below code doesn't work):

```
define variable randomvariable as character initial "fieldname" NO-UNDO.

define temp-table tt_table
field VALUE(randomvariable) AS CHARACTER.
```

Many Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Please provide more details about your use-case. What are you going to use the dynamic temp-table field for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As bupereira pointed out, this requires a dynamic-temp-table. To define/create the dynamic-temp-table, do this here:

```
DEFINE VARIABLE randomvariable AS CHARACTER INITIAL "fieldname" NO-UNDO.

DEFINE VARIABLE hTempTable AS HANDLE NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE hBuffer    AS HANDLE NO-UNDO.

CREATE TEMP-TABLE hTempTable .

hTempTable:ADD-NEW-FIELD (randomvariable, "CHARACTER") .

// Optional, but good practive when temp-table becomes large
hTempTable:ADD-NEW-INDEX("myPrimaryIndex",
                         TRUE, // unique
                         TRUE, // primary
                         FALSE // no word-index
                         ) .
hTempTable:ADD-INDEX-FIELD ("myPrimaryIndex", randomvariable) .

hTempTable:TEMP-TABLE-PREPARE ("tt_table") .

hBuffer = hTempTable:DEFAULT-BUFFER-HANDLE .
```

then create some records using the default buffer:

```
hBuffer:BUFFER-CREATE () .
hBuffer:BUFFER-FIELD (randomvariable):BUFFER-VALUE = "Hello" .

hBuffer:BUFFER-CREATE () .
hBuffer:BUFFER-FIELD (randomvariable):BUFFER-VALUE = "World" .
hBuffer:BUFFER-RELEASE .
```

and then use one of the default buffer's FIND... methods or dynamic queries to access the records:

```
hBuffer:FIND-FIRST (SUBSTITUTE ("where &1 = &2",
                                randomvariable,
                                QUOTER ("World"))) .
MESSAGE hBuffer:BUFFER-FIELD (randomvariable):BUFFER-VALUE .
```

Answer (score 3):

This can work if your temp-table is dynamic. Look into these links, first one for dynamic temp-table syntax, second to create your own fields.

Dynamic temp-tables:
https://documentation.progress.com/output/ua/OpenEdge_latest/index.html#page/dvref/create-temp-table-statement.html

Add-new-field syntax:
https://documentation.progress.com/output/ua/OpenEdge_latest/index.html#page/dvref/add-new-field(-)-method.html

Answer (score 2):

The closer to what you write is to define a preprocesor with the variable value and reuse it in the temp-table definition, like:

```
&global-define myvar fieldname
define variable randomvariable as character initial "{&myvar}" NO-UNDO.
define temp-table tt_table
field {&myvar} AS CHARACTER.
```

This works as long as your intent was not to be able to define the field name at runtime.